# internet explorer problem with a javascript page

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have made a page

The url [here](http://pradyut.dyndns.org/)

It works fine in ff/chrome

But the whole login form and reg form are not displayed in ie

and the shout box is not working in ie...

Any help

Thanks

Pradyut

India

Comment: you don't need to mention your signature in your Question, it's already there in your profile :) If you got some time please do visit http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures

Comment: There should be corporal punishment for reporting IE-specific bugs without version number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HTML is [not valid](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fpradyut.dyndns.org%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0):

You need to fix (at least ) **13 errors** before you can start IE specific bugfixing.

I guess if you do that many problems will vanish ;)